# Conditionally removing items in related lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

Two lists: one contains redshifts and the other contains the error in these redshifts. I have written a short bit of code that successfully checks the redshift list, identifies values above three sigma from the mean and removes them then recalculates the average and standard deviation and repeats this until there aren't any items in the list above three sigma from the mean. My question: how do I not only remove the redshift from the first list but also remove its corresponding error from the second list? I tried this code below but I'm certain it is wrong. I'm not sure how to say "item in z" in the conditional statement for dz. Please forgive me for my sloppy code. I'm sure there is a way to make it more succinct.

```
for item in z:
    if absolute(item - average(z)) > 3 * std(z):
        z = [item for item in z if absolute(item - average(z)) < 3 * std(z)]
        dz = [item for item in dz if absolute((item in z) - average(z)) < 3 * std(z)]
```

Comment: three hints: 1- you're looping over the items twice (once in the for, other in the list comprehension). 2- [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). 3- You're recalculating average(z) and std(z) `len(z)` times. You should pre-calculate them instead

Comment: @goncalopp the OP's list comprehensions *do* build new lists

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed, I misread the `for`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
z = numpy.array(z)
mask = [None]
while not all(mask): #loop until all elements of z are within 3 sigma
    mask = numpy.abs(z - numpy.average(z)) < 3 * numpy.std(z)
    z = z[mask]   # meets condition above
print z
```

numpy is your friend

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to try to rebuild `z` while you're already iterating over it. Also, it's very inefficient to calculate the average and standard deviation of `z` so many times. One straightforward, index-based approach would be:

```
z_ave = average(z)
z_std = std(z)

indices = set(index for index, item in enumerate(z) 
              if abs(item - z_ave) >= (3 * z_std))

z = [item for index, item in enumerate(z) if index not in indices]
dz = [item for index, item in enumerate(dz) if index not in indices]
```

Comment: afaik he is changing z each time and re-calculating ... not simply recalculating ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley sorry, don't follow

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what I'm trying to do is calculate the average and standard deviation of z, cut out elements of the list that are above 3 sigma from the mean, then recalculate the average and standard deviation (since they will have changed) and repeat the process over again.

Comment: @Shylos you can wrap the whole thing in a loop, and `break` once you're not getting any `indices`